# Time Manager to animate time series in multiple columns?

Tags: qgis, timemanager

I have a vector file of Africa containing all its countries. I have a CSV file containing a time series of monthly precipitation per African country. Is there a way to use Time Manager (or anything else) in computing a series of images containing all countries with their corresponding precipitation value over time?

So what I would like to achieve is an image of Africa with all countries having a different color based on a precipitation-value, and this for every month over a period of about 30 years. Obviously I would like to avoid having to make 12 x 30 separate images myself.

[image: Africa shapefile containing all countries]

[image: csv containing precip time series per African country]

Tutorials that I find only show how to use Time Manager with a CSV that contains spatial data, which is not the case for me. If I add all the precip-data as columns to the attribute table of the Africa shapefile, I have the problem of only being able to select one column for Time Manager to run. If I do it the other way around I can only do it for one country in stead of all countries simultaneously.

Any suggestions as to how I can achieve this?

Comment: Try:

 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GkfoFFy-bao 
 
 - https://anitagraser.com/2011/11/20/nice-animations-with-time-managers-offset-feature/

Comment: Similar to [How to visualize car park occupancy over time?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136132/how-to-visualize-car-park-occupancy-over-time)

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not possible to use multiple columns with timestamps. 
If you are able to provide a pull request to add the feature and accompanying tests, please feel free to do so.

For now, you have to reformat your data to use it with TimeManager.